# Connect to Oracle as SYSDBA using OCI or SQL*Plus, from client machine

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle-call-interface, oracle12c

I'm using Instant-Client 12.1.0.2.0, connecting to a 12.1.0.1.0 (Linux) server, in **Multi-Tenant** configuration.

Using either:

- SQL*Plus
- OCILogon2
- OCIServerAttach + OCISessionBegin(OCI_RDBMS credentials, OCI_DEFAULT mode)

I can connect (using EZCONNECT, no environment variables at all) from a client machine to a PDB on the server, using SYSTEM. E.g.

```
c:\>sqlplus system@'//host/pdb12c_1.domain.net'

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Tue Oct 20 11:14:10 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
Last Successful login time: Tue Oct 20 2015 11:10:10 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> quit
```

But as soon as I add as SYSDBA to the command line, it fails:

```
c:\>sqlplus system@'//host/pdb12c_1.domain.net' as SYSDBA

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Tue Oct 20 11:14:22 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

I've modified my OCI application to use OCI_SYSDBA as the mode to OCISessionBegin, and it fails the same way. I've tried SYSOPER with both SQL*Plus and my OCI client app, and it also fails the same way.

What am I missing? What kind of restriction are placed on connection that want to gain SYSDBA? Is this mode impossible from a client machine? Or is that because I connect to a PDB instead of the CDB?

I'd appreciate some insights. Thanks.

PS: yes, I double and triple checked I typed the password in correctly

Comment: If it were due to restriction, you would have gotten a different error. `invalid username/password` error is very specific that username password combination is wrong

Comment: I tried it again after your comment. Without `as SYSDBA` it works, and with it, it fails. Exactly like shown above. So I believe you are not correct.

Comment: have you tried the following: sqlplus system as sysdba@'//host/pdb12c_1.domain.net'

Comment: The [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_three.htm#SQPUG368) clearly shows the syntax I showed is correct. I tried yours though, and that yields the help message. including `<logon> is: {<username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>] | / } [AS {SYSDBA | SYSOPER | SYSASM | SYSBACKUP | SYSDG | SYSKM}] [EDITION=value]`

Comment: **SYS can't connect without SYSOPER/SYSDBA option** You are using `SYSTEM`. Use `SYS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> c:>sqlplus system@'//host/pdb12c_1.domain.net' as SYSDBA

You are using **SYSTEM** user which is incorrect. You need to use **SYS**.

For example,

```
C:\Users\lkb>sqlplus sys@pdborcl as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Tue Oct 20 15:11:25 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you. You wrote that SYS cannot connect **without** SYSDBA/SYSOPER, but what applies here instead is that SYSTEM cannot connect **with** SYSDBA/SYSOPER. Said differently, SYSDBA/SYSOPER can only be used with **SYS**. Correct? (BTW, my OCI app also works when using SYS as SYSDBA. Resolved!)

Comment: It depends if you have granted `SYSDBA` to a user then you can connect it `AS SYSDBA`. But, beware, SYS/SYSDBA is special. It is not for general purpose. SYSTEM doesn't need SYSDBA, and if you try to connect SYS without SYSDBA, you cannot. That's what happened in your case, you tried to login SYS without SYSDBA and you got logon denied. You must use SYSDBA for SYS.

Comment: Thanks, For the record, I tried SYSTEM as SYSDBA, not SYS without SYSDBA.

Comment: Ok. If you were able to login SYSTEM AS SYSDBA, then it means SYSTEM was granted the SYSDBA privilege.